# How to turn string into HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have static html stored in javascript string literal templates.

On button click, (modal popup) I need to pass the stored static html through a function and update elements in it with dynamic data that gets stored in a hidden `div`.

**I need the html static string to become a HTML Collection**, so I can perform jQuery functions on it for finding and replacing elements in it with the dynamic content stored in the hidden `div`s.

**How do I do that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var htmlString = "<div class='abc'><p>Lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet..</p></div>";
var html = $(htmlString);
```

It creates an element wrapped in jQuery, so you can perform it's methods on it and when you're finished, you can [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it to your modal.

Comment: Thanks, so simple. I am curious, for the future uses, how would you do it in normal Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `var HTMLAsString = "<div id="dynamicDivId">This is paragraph</div>"` is the HTML which you want to add to modal

```
<div id="modalDivId">
    <div id="hiddenDivId">some data</div>
</div>
```

To get following output

```
<div id="modalDivId">
    <div id="hiddenDivId">some data</div>
    <div>some data</div>
</div>
```

You can do something like this

```
var dynamicDivSelector = $(HTMLAsString);
dynamicDivSelector.text($("#hiddenDivId").text());
$("#modalDivId").append(dynamicDivSelector);
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in the comments as to how to accomplish this in plain JavaScript, you'd need to do the following:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.className = 'foo';
var markup = '<p>blah blah blah...</p>';
newDiv.innerHTML = markup;
```

You can then do whatever you need to do with the new node, and insert it to the DOM with something like:

```
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```